# Scanner problems in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a method that returns a scanner to a text file that has lines of input (I can't get this to display properly, but like - Hi (new line) This (\n) Is (\n) Me (\n)). Then in main, I used the scanner to count the number of lines of input there are, and then resetted the scanner. I later used the scanner to put the lines of input into an array (I don't want an ArrayList), but Java says "java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found"...

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
    numOfStrings++;
    scanner.nextLine();
}

scanner.reset();
String[] stringsOfInput = new String[numOfStrings];
for(int i = 0; i < numOfStrings; i++){
    String s = scanner.nextLine();   //returns "No line found" error message
    stringsOfInput[i] = s;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this so it does what it should?

Comment: `reset()` doesn't do what you think it does - from the [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#reset%28%29) - _Resetting a scanner discards all of its explicit state information which may have been changed by invocations of `useDelimiter(java.util.regex.Pattern)`, `useLocale(java.util.Locale)`, or `useRadix(int)`._ Resetting the `Scanner` cannot rewind the stream.

Comment: I think you need another scanner to save the lines later, reset won't start the file from the begining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most versatile way to do this would be to add the lines into an `ArrayList<String>` then make that into an Array(`String[] stringsOfInput = myArrayList.toArray(new String[myArrayList.size()]);`)

Comment: That would, of course, be ideal, but OP said "input into an array (I don't want an ArrayList)"

Comment: But maybe a `List` is okay... Ha! I was more commenting to the OP than to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try putting the content of the for loop within the while.  That way you can get the number of strings and each string in one loop through the file.

EDIT:
Sample with ArrayList

```
ArrayList<String> stringsOfInput = new ArrayList<String>();

while(scanner.hasNextLine())
{
    stringsOfInput.add(scanner.nextLine());
    numOfStrings++;
}
```

Comment: Thing is, because I'm using an array, not an ArrayList, Java won't let me do that because there is nothing at index 0, so I can't insert the lines of input. I need to know the size of the array so I can do `String[] s = new String[?]` and THEN put in the input - but with just `String[] s = {};` I can't do that.

Comment: If its required to use an array, you could use and ArrayList<String> like GreySwordz mentions.  ArrayList's are not fixed like a Array.  Edited answer with sample code.